# Compare text files with grep

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Lets say I have two files, I want to find goodbye which I can do with grep but what i'm struggling with is once I find goodbye matching the next line with the first column of file 1.

File1

`sss aa 0030
 asa bb 0040`

File 2

`Hello, goodbye sjkd askdfj al;j
asa but no I dont need this 
sfajkld goodbye sjakdlfja
sss saklfj alkjfalskj`

something like

`if(line has goodbye && nextline has first column in file 1)
   print the second column in file 1`

Comment: If you want to use pure grep, something like `grep -A 1` might be useful. See `man grep` for more info.

Comment: I would have to think that awk would be your best bet on this one.  But I would have to defer to one of the awk gurus to assist you... But if you were looking for just a suggestion that would be it, but unfortunately I can't help with a walk through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { a[$1] = $2 ; next }
  c && c-- && ($1 in a) { print a[$1] }
  /goodbye/ { c = 1 }
' File1 File2
```

How this works:

`NR==FNR` is a condition that is only true when reading the first file; here we store in a map the second field under the key value defined by the first field. With the `next` statement no other of the subsequent conditions will be checked for the first data file.

So the rest of the conditions will be checked only for the second file. We want to print the mapped value from the first file (depending on the key of the second file) if certain conditions are true; a flag `c` has been set (if so, that flag will be decremented to 0), and the current key value must already exist as key (from the first file) in the map `a`. Finally the flag `c` will be set if the condition is true that the given pattern is matched.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer for that.